# Is there such a thing as an Architecture Roadmap, Flowchart, or Diagram for when to use some technologies depending on a projects requirements?

Tags: architecture, hosting

Non english-native speaker here.
I'll explain as clear as I can, because I don't know if such a thing exists.
Im' looking for some type of chart or graphic resource that recommends certain technologies depending on the different specifications of a project (in this case web apps).

For example:

*Axis X would be the load an app can get.* 
Like the number of simultaneous users by minute, or the number of POST request the server gets by the hour.

*Axis Y would be the number of records on a database*.
It really could be anything on Axis Y, it's just what comes to mind right now.

Then, the chart would recommend things like:

- when is wise to change from a simple shared hosting, to a vps, then
  from vps to aws or docker.
- when php+mysql is enough for the backend, but then it would recommend when is better to just develop in NodeJS, or things like
  Rails.
- and just like that with front-end, like html+jquery but then VueJS or Angular before that.

Just reading it now it seems that a thing with axis wouldn't be too practical, but oh well.
I don't even know if I'm asking in the right place. The question comes from actually implementing what I think is the right choice for all the new projects in my current job. We are a small team and constantly developing new things from scratch so we can make our own choices (as long as we deliver, of course). 
The "hardest" change we have had to make was to migrate all our projects to 2 VPS (several domains, projects, api's and such), which was actually pretty simple.

Hope someone has some tips.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something you can create a decision-flowchart out of.  Architecture is a balancing act, and very few things (like rowcount) can rule out one solution or another.  So much depends on the use-cases involved, the constraints of the project, the constraints of the developers, etc, that you cannot make a simple decision matrix.

I wish that such a simple decision-process could be made, it would simplify our jobs tremendously (although architects likely would not be paid very well).  But the fact of the matter is, too many variables feed into a decision like these.